# Where am I going wrong with this Python annuity function?

Tags: python, finance, calculation, annuity

I have this python function where I am creating an annuity whose value doubles every 2nd year. I have attempted two approaches, the first is recursive, however I get an error 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison' or that the type is None (when I run the function as annu(10000, 40,0.1045)

```
def annu(MNY, n, i):
    k=MNY/i 
    c=((1+i)**(n-1))-1 
    FV=k*c
    FV1=0 
    FV2=0
    for y in range(1, n):
        if (y%2)==1:
            FV1=annu(MNY,(n),i)
            print('FV1 is', FV1)
            return round(FV1,3)
        else:
            FV2=2*FV1
            print('FV2 is', FV2)
            return round(FV2,2)
        FV=FV1+FV2
        inv_bal=FV
        return round(inv_bal,1)
```

The second involves no recursion, however this gives me an incorrect answer:

```
def inp(PMT, n,i):
    balance=0
    FV1=0
    FV2=0

    k=PMT/i

    c=((1+i)**n)-1

    FV=k*c

    for j in range(0,n):


        if j%2==1:
            FV=2*((FV)*(1+i)**(n-1))
            interest=balance*i

            balance=balance+interest + PMT

            FV1=FV1+balance
            print('FV1 is', FV1)
         else:
            FV2=2*((FV1)*(1+i)**(n-1))
            interest=balance*i

            balance=balance+interest + PMT

            FV2=FV2+balance
            print('FV2 is', FV2)
            FV=FV1+FV2
            print('inv_bal', FV)
            inv_bal=FV
```

I am expecting an answer of around 4*10**9 if I run it as annu(10000,40,0.1045)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software development.

Comment: I would definitely take this to StackOverflow, but to save you the trouble, just follow the recursive function through line-by-line and it should quickly become apparent why you're entering infinite recursion.